# Cisco AIRONET 700 loses connection while downloading

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, aironet

We have three of them, but one is messing around. As soon as you download a bigger file, he loses connection. I can't ping the AP (from another PC connected via LAN), and the PC connected via Wi-Fi can't ping anything (ping 8.8.8.8).

So I started to check when this happens. I ping 500 times 8.8.8.8 and download a file. As soon is the download starts, 8.8.8.8 isn't reachable, and also the AP isn't. When the download aborts, everything works again.

Tested the same with the other APs, but they don't have this issue.

The APs are connected to the same switch. I also checked if there is an IP error, like another one is using the same IP address as the AP, but no, he is the only one. Interesting thing is, that the "broken" AP shows only 100 Mb Ethernet Connection, while the other are showing 1 Gb.

I don't know where to start looking. Maybe it's hardware failure?

Comment: That sounds like a layer-1 problem. You need to check the interfaces on both ends of the links to make sure they are set to Auto/Auto, and you need to test the cable. A 1000BASE-T connection will fall back to 100BASE-TX if the interfaces cannot use all four pairs. You should always start trouble shooting at layer-1. When you rule that out, move on to layer-2, etc.

Comment: Checked the Configuration, switch & AP are set on auto. Both are FULL Duplex. What's also interisting, while pinging there are some ping with a response time over 10ms .. I'll change the cable.

Comment: Changed Cable, Seeing 10M Connection on the Switch with other Port. AP isn't reachable any more. Logging in via console atm. Think the conf is missing.

Comment: Seems to be the cable which is in the wall. Testing several ports on the patch field - on one it is working.

Comment: OK. I will post an answer so that you can accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a layer-1 problem.

You need to check the interfaces on both ends of the links to make sure they are set to Auto/Auto, and you need to test the cable. A 1000BASE-T connection will fall back to 100BASE-TX if the interfaces cannot use all four pairs.

You should always start trouble shooting at layer-1. When you rule that out, move on to layer-2, etc.